# Trying to open 2 different xml page using 2 different buttons

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, button

I have written the following code:

```
public class FragmentFirstPage extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{


View root;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle){

    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false); 

    Button bt = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button mbt = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    mbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById (R.id.activity_main_viewpager);

         @Override
          public void onClick (View v){
          viewPager.setCurrentItem (viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1); //or -1 to go previous

          } 
    });             
    return root;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SplashActivity.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);

}
```

When I run it, it doesn't show any error but doesn't work either. It shows an error message saying unfortunately app has stopped working. What should I do to get this right my xml page has 2 buttons button1 open an activity and imagebutton1 shows the next fragment. This is what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is check inside your `onClick` which button was clicked by checking the id of the calling view. From there you can decide what each one will do.

```
public class beforemain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.beforemain);

    Button mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button mBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); //Just like #1
    mBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    mBtn2.setOnClickListener(this); //Also like #1

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) { //Get the id of the button that was clicked
    case R.id.button1:
        Intent i = new Intent(beforemain.this, Splash1.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        Intent i = new Intent(beforemain.this, Splash2.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help you out.

Comment: ok everything is working but when i try to add a sound pool it never plays the track.

Comment: Hi; could you please look at the question again i have just updated it  could you please help me solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

change implementation of onClick method as follows..

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.beforemain);

    Button mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button mBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(mBtn1.getId()==v.getID())
   {
    Intent i1=new Intent(beforemain.this, Splash1.class);
    startActivity(i1);
   }
   else
   {
        Intent i=new Intent(beforemain.this, Splash2.class);
        startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Button mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button mBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
mBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
mBtn2.setOnClickListener(this); 




 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id = v.getId();
            switch(id) {
            case R.id.button1:

       Intent i=new Intent(beforemain.this, Splash1.class);
        startActivity(i);

                break;
            case R.id.button2:

    Intent i=new Intent(beforemain.this, Splash2.class);
        startActivity(i);
                break;

        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the `onClickListener` for all your buttons and then compare their ids in `if else` or a `switch` case and do whatever you want to do

For eg.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
  if(v.getId()==R.id.button1)
  {
    Intent i=new Intent(beforemain.this, Splash1.class);
    startActivity(i);
  }
  else if(v.getId()==R.id.button2)
  {
    Intent i=new Intent(beforemain.this, Splash2.class);
    startActivity(i);}
  }
}
```