# How can i call a class using button

Tags: java, android, class

I want to call a class using button created in the fragment. This is the code for the fragment which contains the button.

```
public class FragmentSecondPage extends Fragment{

    View root;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle){
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page2, container, false); 
        return root;
    }
}
```

I want to start a class SplashActivity.class from the button present infragment_page2. Could somebody please help me?

Comment: first you can start using google: How to start new activity on button click. Then you can click on the first result which brings you to stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click

Comment: How is this different from you [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227412/trying-to-open-2-different-xml-page-using-2-different-buttons) that I answered?

Comment: the problem was that i was getting an error msg at the line

Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
i had to convert it to


Button bt = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button1);
could you please tell me the difference for future reference and i got it running your code itself thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Create Intent that would call the Next Activity and since you are in Fragment you need to call getActivity() instead of this
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SplashActivity.class);
// This function will replace the currently running activity with new one
getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Please comment the code as well...

Comment: Fragment is part of activity, thus its not activity findviewbyid is method of class Activity not Fragment thus you need to call the current activity using getActivity().whateverfunction()